# Two overlapping triangles $\triangle ABC$, $\triangle DBE$. Given some angles and sides, find the area of the Blue triangle $\triangle ABC$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, triangles

The problem is as described in the title. In the following figure, we have two triangles $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle DBE$, with some side-lengths and angle measures given. The goal is to find the area of the blue triangle:

[image]

The source of this problem is my good friend on Instagram @dare2solve who posts problems like these. They can also be found on the site that he listed in the picture above. I will post my approach to this problem as an answer below, please share your own approaches as well, and let me know if there is anything wrong with my approach or if my answer is incorrect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problems you (and maybe your friend :)) propose, are (in general) supposed to be solved in an entirely geometric way. However, I am posting my solution which follows a very straightforward path.

Let's assume $\angle DBC=\theta$. Then,

$$\frac{\sin (115^{\circ}-\theta)}{\sin \theta}=\frac{BC}{DC}=\frac{DE}{DC}=\frac{\sin 115^{\circ}}{\sin 50^{\circ}}\implies \\\cos (65^{\circ}-\theta) -\cos(165^{\circ}-\theta)=\cos(115^{\circ}-\theta)-\cos(115^{\circ}+\theta)\implies \\-\cos(165^{\circ}-\theta)=\cos(115^{\circ}-\theta)\implies \\ \cos (15^{\circ}+\theta)=\cos(115^{\circ}-\theta)\implies \\ 15^{\circ}+\theta=115^{\circ}-\theta\implies \theta=50^{\circ};$$

and the rest is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach using some angle-chasing:

[image]

1.) Rotate $\triangle DEC$ counterclockwise by $115^\circ$ such that the new triangle $\triangle BCF$ formed is congruent to $\triangle DEC$. Join $D$ and $F$ via segment $DF$, $C$ and $F$ via $CF$ and lastly $E$ and $F$ via $EF$. Notice that $\angle FCD=\angle ECD=115^\circ$ as well as $CF=CE$. This implies that $\triangle DFC$ is congruent to $\triangle DEC$ via the SAS property.

2.) It follows that $\angle DFC=50^\circ$, $\angle FDC=15^\circ$ and $DE=DF=BC=AB=1$. Notice that $BC=DF$ and $DC=BF$ via congruence of triangles. This then implies that Quadrilateral $BFCD$ is an isosceles trapezoid, which means that it is a Cyclic Quadrilateral. Therefore, we can exploit the propertied of cyclic quadrilaterals and conclude that $\angle BDF=\angle BCF=50^\circ$. Notice that this means $\angle BDC=\angle BCD=65^\circ$, therefore, $DE=DF=BC=AB=BD=1$.

3.) Lastly, its easy to see that point $B$, is a circumcenter to $\triangle ACD$, therefore $\angle ACD=\frac{\angle ABD}{2}=5^\circ$. This implies that $\angle ACB=65^\circ -5^\circ=60^\circ$. This means that the blue triangle $\triangle ABC$ is an equilateral triangle. Therefore, the area of an equilateral triangle with side length $1$ is:

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} u^2$$ ($u=$ unit)